# How to make an Accordion component with Reactstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reactstrap

[Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/) does not have an official sample for **Accordion** in the documentation.

> Using the card component, you can extend the default collapse behavior to create an accordion. To properly achieve the accordion style, be sure to use .accordion as a wrapper.

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have Accordion component like Bootstrap 4 documentation sample?

Comment: You can use other framework:react-bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/accordion/

Comment: @RyanNghiem - using another framework is typically not a good suggestion as it circumvents the question entirely and often doesn't provide an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Reactstrap docs](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/) is right. You can create an accordion using `Card` and `Collapse` components.
    First, initialize your constructor and state.

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
      this.state = { collapse: 0, cards: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
    }
```

And then your method to toggle/collapse the accordion.

```
    toggle(e) {
      let event = e.target.dataset.event;
      this.setState({ collapse: this.state.collapse === Number(event) ? 0 : Number(event) });
    }
```

And the `render()` function:

```
render() {
  const {cards, collapse} = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <h3 className="page-header">Reactstrap Accordion using card component</h3>
        {cards.map(index => {
          return (
            <Card style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }} key={index}>
              <CardHeader onClick={this.toggle} data-event={index}>Header</CardHeader>
              <Collapse isOpen={collapse === index}>
              <CardBody>Example</CardBody>
              </Collapse>
            </Card>
          )
        })}     

      </div>
  );
}
```

And don't forget to import:

```
import { Collapse, CardBody, Card, CardHeader } from 'reactstrap';
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/yasharma/reactstrap-card-accordion)

Comment: This should be a comment. Please expand your answer with code snippets. See Stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: How to add it with latest react-strap code? 
https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-accordion--accordion

Answer (score 8):

If you use reactstrap and react Hooks you can do it as follows

1 import the required components from reactstrap

```
import { Collapse, CardBody, Card, CardHeader} from 'reactstrap';
```

2- import useState from react

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
```

3- within your component create your states

```
const [toggleQuestion, setToggequestion] = useState(1);//1 is the default id to be opened by default
```

4- Create your accordion. Note: in my case I only toggle the body but you can toggle everything by moving the collapse.

```
<Card>
    <CardHeader onClick={() => setToggequestion(1)}>
        <span className="font-weight-bold">title</span>
    </CardHeader>
    <Collapse  isOpen={toggleQuestion === 1 ? true : false}>
        <CardBody>
            example text
        </CardBody>
    </Collapse>
</Card>

<Card>
    <CardHeader onClick={() => setToggequestion(2)}>
        <span className="font-weight-bold">title 2</span>
    </CardHeader>
    <Collapse  isOpen={toggleQuestion === 2 ? true : false}>
        <CardBody>
            example text 2
        </CardBody>
    </Collapse>
</Card>
```

Now you can create as many as you want and only need to change the ID. In my case the id was just 1 and 2